# Create Procedure to extract subgraph from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, graph, cursor, subgraph

I have the following schema that represents a graph stored in MySQL.

```
Nodes

Id | Type


Links
Id | Source_id | Dest_id
```

where source_id and dest_id are foreign key of the Nodes table.
Each node can have multiple links.

I want to create a stored  procedure to retrieve a subgraph starting from a given id of a node in the graph.
I was looking at this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58c804/1, but it works only if each node has a single link. I think I should use CURSOR but I don't know how to make it working.

@C_B What I tried is the following:

I have the following tree:

```
            5
            |
            1
          /    \
         2      3 
        /
       4

CREATE TABLE Nodes
      (`id` int, `type` varchar(10))

CREATE TABLE Links
      (`id` int, `source_id` int, `dest_id` int)

INSERT INTO Nodes
     (`id`, `type`)
VALUES
     (1, 'a'),
     (2, 'b'),
     (3, 'c'),
     (4, 'd'),
     (5, 'e')

INSERT INTO Links
     (`id`, `source_id`, `dest_id`)
VALUES
     (1, 1, 2),
     (2, 1, 3),
     (3, 2, 4),
     (4, 5, 1)


CREATE PROCEDURE get_subgraph(IN id int)
BEGIN
DECLARE prev_id int;
DECLARE child_id int;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
SET prev_id = id;
DECLARE child_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT dest_id FROM Links WHERE source_id=prev_id ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN child_cursor;
FETCH child_cursor INTO child_id;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results AS (SELECT * FROM Links WHERE 1=0);
TRUNCATE TABLE results

WHILE child_id <> 0 DO
     INSERT INTO results SELECT * FROM Links WHERE source_id=prev_id;
     SET prev_id = child_id;
     SET child_id=0;
     FETCH child_cursor INTO child_id;
     IF done THEN
         SET done = FALSE;
         CLOSE child_cursor;
         DECLARE child_cursor CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT dest_id FROM results WHERE source_id=prev_id;
         DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
         OPEN child_cursor;
         FETCH child_cursor INTO child_id;
     END IF
END WHILE;
SELECT * FROM results;
END
```

I want to call 
    CALL get_subgraph(1);

And having the following result:

Results

```
id | source_id | dest_id
1  | 1         | 2
2  | 1         | 3
3  | 2         | 4
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Could you provide some code of your attempt?

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the help